# How to register cut/paste (by jsni) method to RichTextArea?

Tags: javascript, gwt, dom-events, richtextbox

Following code is used to set attribute style to body element and register cut/paste code to it, but failed. Strangely, when debugging, variable `body` is not null and attribute "style" exists, but frame hasn't this child. Running work doesn't work as expected,and NPE got thrown out when call `setBodyContent()`.

```
public class TextAreaExt extends RichTextArea
{
private BodyElement body;

@Override
protected void onLoad()
{
    super.onLoad();
    body = ((FrameElement) getElement().cast())
                .getContentDocument().getBody();
    body.setAttribute("style", "color:gray;");
    registerOnCut(body);
}

public void setBodyContent(String text)
{
    body.setInnerText(text);
}

private native void registerOnCut(BodyElement element) /*-{
    var that = this;
    console.log("registerOnCut");
    element.oncut = $entry(function(event) {
        //invoke method to adjust height based on content
        return false;
    });
    element.onpaste = $entry(function(event) {
        //invoke method to adjust height based on content
        return false;
    });
}-*/;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't invoke the `onLoad` method to initialize the body, initialize it by making use of the `addInitializeHandler`.

```
  this.addInitializeHandler(new InitializeHandler() {

        @Override
        public void onInitialize(InitializeEvent event) {
            body = ((FrameElement)getElement().cast()).getContentDocument().getBody();
            registerOnCut(body);
        }
    });
```